# Extrinsic lifetime

Tags: extrinsic

How can I get the lifetime of an extrinsic?. There is a way to estimate the lifetime of the extrinsics per chain?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime is set by the api-client/app/wallet when they send the extrinsic.

There isn't such a parameter on the chain.

Simply query the extrinsic, and then you can extract this field from it.